# GnuPlot auto set xlabel (or ylabel), reading from column head of CSV file

Tags: python, gnuplot

In GnuPlot, I can auto set a plot legend with `title columnhead` option in a plot command like:

```
plot 'test.txt' using 0:1 w linespoints title columnhead
```

So it reads the column name from the CSV file and use it in the legend.

[image]
[image]

I would like the same to set xlabel and ylabel. Is is possible?

(Also, I'm interested in knowing how one will do such thing in Python. Is it better than GnuPlot? Should I learn Python instead?)

Comment: No, gnuplot doesn't support reading `xlabel` and `ylabel` from the data file. You would need to do it yourself with some shell command via `system`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as pointed out by @Christoph, the `system` command is probably the only viable solution - in your particular case, you could do:

```
fname="test.txt"

getTitle(colNum)=system(sprintf("head -n1 '%s' | cut -f%d -d';'", fname, colNum+1))

set xlabel getTitle(0)
set ylabel getTitle(1)
```